# Forwarding logs from file to journald

Tags: unix, logging, centos, systemd

I have an application on the isolated machine. It writes logs to /var/log/app/log.txt for example. However, I want it to write logs to journald daemon. However, I can't change the way application run, because it is encapsulated.

I mean I can not do smth like `app | systemd-cat`

**1)** Am I right that all services started with systemd write logs to journald?

**2)** If so, will the children of process, started by systemd, will also write logs to journald?

**3)** Is there any way to tell journald to take logs from a specific file?

**4)** If not, are there any workarounds?

Comment: Ok, I've found out answers for the first two questions

1) yes
2) yes

Answer (score 1):

**warning:** this is not tested

You could mount bind `/dev/stdout` to  log file in `ExecStartPre`

Example:

```
ExecStartPre=/use/sbin/mount --bind /dev/stdout  /var/log/app/log.txt
```

Or soft link `/dev/stdout` to  log file in `ExecStartPre`

Example:

```
ExecStartPre=/use/bin/ln -s /dev/stdout  /var/log/app/log.txt
```

Comment: I don't think this will work as /dev/stdout is 1) per-process and 2) itself a symlink

Answer (score 0):

4) I can only try to help with a workaround:

```
MY_LOG_FILE=/var/log/app/log.txt

# Create a FIFO PIPE
PIPE=/tmp/my_fifo_pipe
mkfifo $PIPE
MY_IDENTIFIER="my_app_name"     # just a label for later searching in journalctl 

# Start logging to journal
systemd-cat -t $MY_IDENTIFIER -p info < $PIPE &
exec 3>$PIPE

tail -f $MY_LOG_FILE > $PIPE &

exec 3>&- #closing file descriptor 3 closes the fifo
```

This is the basic idea, you should now think about timings, when it's needed to have this started and when to be stopped.